# Can you display mxd files on a app for iPads?

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-10.2, mxd, mapping, ipad

I would like to know if there is any apps that can displaying ArcGIS data?

I have multiple .mxd's that i would like to display on a portable app.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - No.  MXDs don't actually contain data, they're just containers that point to data that is stored somewhere else (as a shapefile, or in a file or personal geodatabase, or maybe as a KML/GPX).

There are various ways to display that data on a mobile device.  If you're using ESRI products, [ArcGIS Online](https://www.arcgis.com/home/) is the most direct route.  I would recommend starting there.  There are lots of other options available as well but they require a bit more heavy lifting and setup.

When properly set up, ArcGIS Online will let you build a map as an MXD and then use that to publish a web map - but - as I pointed out first - there's not a direct way to display an MXD on a mobile device.

Comment: I assume that is a monthly fee? and would i be able to publish maps to various people with the same account?

Comment: There are free accounts that let you make maps and publish them to the web but they are limited.  I'm not certain what the limitations are off - you'd have to check on their website.  The paid subscriptions have a lot of different options available - again, check the website to find out what the differences between plans are.